# CodeDom InitExpression for Typed Dictionary type

Tags: c#, dictionary, codedom

There are a couple of questions similar to this, on StackExchange, but they don't cover quite the same case. Please read it through before marking it as a duplicate!

Using CodeDom in C#, I'm trying to generate an Init Expression for a dictionary.
eg

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>{
    {1,"one"},
    {2,"two"}
};
```

I have found other solutions that use a CodeExpression to instantiate the object, and then several CodeStatements that populate the instance, but due to a bunch of boring reasons that's a path I'd rather not go down.

To clarify, since I can't use multiple CodeStatements, I kinda need to avoid generating something like this:

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dict.Add(1,"one");
dict.Add(2,"two");
```

**My question is:** *Is there a way to generate code like this using only CodeDom.CodeExpression(s)?*

I'm pretty sure that at this point the answer is "no.", but thought it would be worth asking just in case.

Comment: So you have like 100000 items that needs to be inserted into a dictionary?  Its too boring to write that code? Is that your issue? Where do those items come from? From a database or something else?

Comment: Is `CodeSnippetExpression` (i.e. building the expression by yourself as a string) acceptable?

Comment: @KosalaW It's more that Im trying to reflect a corpus of data that supports dictionaries within lists within structures within lists within structures etc etc. Building an expression tree to initialise these things works out nicely, but once statements are added I have to start worrying about the context (for example, they have to be in a method and cant be used to initialise an array)

Comment: @svick I had a look at the CodeSnippetExpression, and while its a good suggestion, it means that everything within the dictionary needs to be stringified. This isn't the end of the world but I'd rather avoid it.

Comment: So CodeSnippetExpression ended up working well for me. @svick, if you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll be happy to tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you can't express collection initializers in the CodeDOM object model. But there is a way to work around that: [`CodeSnippetExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codesnippetexpression). Using that, you can create a string that directly contains any C# expression you want and use it inside another CodeDOM object.

You might be able to use the CodeDOM object model and [`GenerateCodeFromExpression()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.generatecodefromexpression) to get parts of the code you need (but you will certainly need to combine those parts by yourself).

Answer (score 1):

No, if you want to use collection initializers you'll need to use LINQ Expressions instead of CodeDOM, e.g. `System.Linq.Expressions.ListInitExpression`.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me, LINQ Expressions tend to have very different use cases than CodeDOM. You can't just substitute one with the other.